# Specify default route in React Router using the 1.0 API

Tags: javascript, react-router

When declaring routes as an **object** using the 1.0 API, how do I specify a default route?

```
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    { name: 'welcome', component: Welcome },
    // Default route here
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same doubt, I have resolved the issue, but not sure whether thats the right way or not, in your "App" component do as follow

```
let App = React.createClass({
    componentDisMount: function() {
        this.transitionTo('deafaultComponent'); 
        //default compoenent you say its your home page. 
        //so when ever somebody used yourwebsite.com/ 
        //it will redirect to yourwebsite.com/defaultComponent
    },
    render: function() {
         {this.props.children}
    }
 );
```